# High resolution Image from Flutter Widget

Tags: image, flutter

In my App, I need to create Images from the Widgets shown on Screen.
I used the below code to create the Image using `RepaintBoundary`.
But the image I get is of 72 PPI.
Is there any way I can get An Image of Higher Resolution?

```dart
Future<void> takePicture() async {
  RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = genKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
  ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
  final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
  Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  File imgFile = new File('$directory/photo.png');
  imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this line will improve the "boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 10.0)"
pixelRatio use as double to improve the quality as u want.

Comment: As far as I know, It doesn't increase the DPI.